# What instrument should be used instead python3? UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte A in position B: invalid start byte

Tags: python

```
$ python3 utf8.py                                             
/usr/bin/torsocks /usr/bin/wget -q -O - --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20
100101 Firefox/17.0" http://xiwayy2kn32bo3ko.onion/test/read.cgi/tor/1371355627/978n                
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "utf8.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = subprocess.getoutput( cmd )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 707, in getoutput
    return getstatusoutput(cmd)[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 683, in getstatusoutput
    text = pipe.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 1674: invalid start byte
```

I migrate to python3, specially to get parse international internet, pages of Chinese etc.
But there i meet this trouble.

My simple code is a python wrapper around wget, because it is easiest way on my sight to dodge the ban.

```
$ cat utf8.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://xiwayy2kn32bo3ko.onion/test/read.cgi/tor/1371355627/978n'
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0"
wget_cmd = '/usr/bin/wget -q -O - --user-agent="' + user_agent + '" '
torsocks_cmd = '/usr/bin/torsocks '
cmd = torsocks_cmd + wget_cmd + url

print( cmd )
data = subprocess.getoutput( cmd )
print( "Fetch complete" )
print( data )
```

http://xiwayy2kn32bo3ko.onion/test/read.cgi/tor/1371355627/978n

Is an example, it is onion-web.

Why codecs.py of python3.3 did not understand everything whatever exist?

subprocess crashed with out any chance to restore fetched data.

Is there universal international way to fetch and parse html pages on any language? I were sure that utf-8 developed for this task.

Target page is: Shift_JIS encoded

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
```

My main question is:
How it should be done for any encoding, any language, universally. What language better to take for that task, how should html be parsed?

What instrument shall i use for such task?

Comment: Whatever you are tying to decode is not valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `subprocess.getoutput()`; it assumes that whatever output was produced by the command is decodable with the same encoding as `sys.stdout` uses.

Try [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead; it returns bytes.

Comment: But me need to parse output. I do import BeautifulSoup, do you see?

Comment: @stackkeeper: what makes you think BeautifulSoup won't be able to handle this? Just pass the `bytes` output to BeautifulSoup *directly*.